# How many squares can be inscribed in a regular polygon?

Tags: geometry

Say that a square $S$ is said to be inscribed in a regular polygon $P$ if all the four vertices of $S$ lie on the boundary of $P$. It is well-known that one can inscribe a square in a regular $n$-gon for $n\geq 5$.

I would like to know, up to rotational symmetry, how many distinct squares can be inscribed? For example, in a hexagon only one square can be inscribed.

Second question: What is the ratio of their side lengths?

Comment: In an octagon you can inscribe infinite different squares (that's obvious by symmetry).

Comment: Maybe we're talking about the _largest possible_ squares; then there are only two.

Comment: @IvanNeretin As far as I can tell, the question is not about squares contained inside a polygon, but about squares inscribed in a polygon, that is squares whose vertices lie on the sides of the polygon. If $n$ is a multiple of four, there are infinite different squares inscribed in a regular $n$-gon. If $n$ is not a multiple of four, I suspect all inscribed squares to be equal.

Comment: @Aretino That was my understanding as well. However, if we want to give this question a meaning, we might want to specifically select the largest of those infinitely many inscribed squares, and then...

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is a multiple of $4$, then every couple of opposite points (with respect to the center) on the polygon can be taken as endpoints of a diagonal of an inscribed square, so in this case we have infinitely many solutions.

In the other cases, it is not difficult to prove that a solution is possible, where the inscribed square has a side parallel to a side of the polygon. I think there are no other solutions, because to find the inscribed square one has to solve a system of linear equations, which can be indeterminate (as in the case when $n$ is a multiple of $4$) but otherwise cannot have more than one solution.